# Integration with logarithm on complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

I want to integrate $$\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{2ie^{it}}{2e^{it}-1}dt$$ Normally, when integrating a real function, $$\int \dfrac1x=\log|x|$$

But here the function is complex. Is it correct to say that

$$\int\dfrac{2ie^{it}}{2e^{it}-1}dt=\log|2e^{it}-1|$$ and therefore $$\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{2ie^{it}}{2e^{it}-1}dt=\log|1|-\log|1|=0?$$

Comment: I assume that when you write the integral from $0$ to $2\pi$, you mean that $t$ runs over the path $[0,2\pi]$ in the real line?

Comment: @AWalker That's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is not correct, since the anti-derivative does not contain the absolute sign:
$$
    \int \frac{2 i \mathrm{e}^{i t}}{2 \mathrm{e}^{i t}-1} \mathrm{d}t = i t + \log\left(2 - \mathrm{e}^{-i t}\right) + C 
$$
The $\log$'s argument $2 - \mathrm{e}^{-i t}$ does not cross $\log$'s branch-cut as $t$ traverses $0\ldots2\pi$, hence the fundamental theorem of calculus applies:
$$
   \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{2 i \mathrm{e}^{i t}}{2 \mathrm{e}^{i t}-1} \mathrm{d}t = \left[ i t + \log\left(2 - \mathrm{e}^{-i t}\right) \right]_0^{2\pi} = 2 \pi i
$$

Alternatively, you could notice that with $z=\mathrm{e}^{i t}$ the integral becomes:
$$
   \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{2 \mathrm{d}z}{2z-1} = \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{ \mathrm{d}z}{z-\tfrac{1}{2}} = \operatorname{Res}_{z=\tfrac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{z-\tfrac{1}{2}} = 2 \pi i
$$

Comment: Are you sure that your anti-derivative is correct?  I have $\log(1-2e^{it})$.  **Edit:** I see, you subtracted out $i$ first to avoid crossing the branch cut.

Comment: So, is it correct to say that the important thing is to avoid the log branch cut, which is the negative real axis? Is that the motivation for pulling $it$ out of the anti-derivative?

Comment: And is $it$ the only value that can be pulled out so that the log branch cut is avoided?